# Sales Order Send by email not working odoo 9.0

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

On click of **Send by email** just page loader starts loading and no mails are sent infact page loads untill I refresh the page.

[attached error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3SCq.png)

Comment: your outgoing mail server is configure or not

Comment: The problem is with mail template coz when I preview the mail templates it doesn't show up it starts loading

Comment: can you share odoo server log

Comment: I am doing it in my local

Comment: in  local odoo also main server log at /var/log/odoo/ , (check the log file path from the odoo-server-config )